# How does the TeamSpeak 3 client execute with high process integrity?

Tags: windows-10, process, teamspeak

My TeamSpeak 3 client is executing at High process integrity with limited elevation when I launch it from the shortcut on my taskbar. How does it do this? Is it because I am a system administrator?

I made a C program to test out if an arbitrary program could set its own process token to high integrity using the `SetTokenInfo(...)` API, but it failed with error 1314 "A required privilege is not held by the client".

How does the TeamSpeak client do it?

EDIT: changed "no elevation" to "limited elevation"

Comment: Most likely you have UAC not configured to the maximum which means that under certain conditions no elevation print is shown.

Comment: I just set UAC to highest and relaunched TS3 but no UAC prompt came up. I'm interested solely in the process integrity being high rather than elevation being limited. It seems odd to me that TS3 is executing with high integrity when it's *just another* program.